# Failed to load resource - Rx.js.map

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react with Rx.js library and I get this error in safari, but not the other browsers. Any idea why? Do I need to specify a setting to not look for map or what? Any clues would greatly help.

Appreciate it!

Comment: Are you importing it in your components ? I remember having that issue but including it in my system js bundle and removed the references in my compnents. Idk if that can lead you anywhere

Comment: Yea, I imported it like:
import Rx from 'rxjs';

Thanks so much for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you have the developer tools active the browser will request source maps. It is [configurable in Chrome or Firefox](https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/336c4982194bcb02ef8a) but not in Safari (I actually went back to look for the setting right now and couldn't find it).

If you are in development mode, just copy the source maps to the folder where the minified file is otherwise don't worry about it as regular clients will not get this 404 (unless they are also using developer tools to explore your project).

Comment: Great to know! Thanks so much :)